# Shape image inside a div

Tags: html, css, slider, shapes

I need to put an image inside a shapped div, the div need to be an heptagon and inside that an image that will fit the div.

Is this possible to do only with HTML+CSS?

I thought to accomplish this with instead of having image inside div, have a background for the div but I think this is not the best practise.

Here my example using normal div with background image of an heptagon and images manually shapped as heptagone too

[Development tests](http://nunosousa.info/glassin/produtos/2/)

Comment: It is possible using CSS Shapes.

Comment: What is the best option then? 
For now I'm editing every image to fit the heptagon form but in the future if anyone else want to add or modify any image it will be necessary image editing.